# Separate mobile apps for business and customers or a single app with different logins?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

I am building a mobile platform to connect shopkeepers and customers.The shopkeepers can post deals, showcase their products etc while customers can check out what near by stores have to offer.

I am a bit confused whether to have 2 different apps - one for shop keepers and one for customers. Or shall I have a single app that has a designated logins for shopkeepers and customers.

After thinking over it for a couple of days, below is what I have been able to figure out (multiple v/s single comparison):

- single will have more updates per app than multiple app. This will be a turn off for the users. **"Win-Multiple"**
- single will definitely be more difficult to build and maintain. **"Win-Multiple"**
- from a features perspective, overlap b/w customers and shopkeepers won't be more than 20%.**"WIn - Mulitple"**

Can any one please suggest me what points shall I keep in mind the most while taking the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the feature overlap is so low, you should really consider to make 2 different apps.

Pros:
- Better maintainability
- Smaller download sizes
- More user-friendly
- Pricing (if any) can be different
- What if a shop keeper is also a customer ?

Cons:
- None

Comment: agree with each of the pros. I was also of the opinion to go for 2 different app. Just wanted to check with developer community.

Comment: This is a common good practice. Keep things simple ;) Please consider to accept the answer if it helped ;)